# Rota e form no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Tenho uma rota

```
Route::get('/','WebController@index');
```

Tenho um controller

```
public function index()
{
    $cars = Cars::table('cars')->get();
    return view('web::index')->with('cars', $cars);
}
```

E no `form` passa a seguinte *URL*

```
{!! Form::open(['class' => 'form-horizontal search-side-box', 'url' => '/', 'method' => 'post', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) !!}
```

Mas quando clico no botão `submit` do `form`, da o seguinte erro:

```
Class App\Front\Http\Controllers\WebController does not exist
```

Mas o controller está configurado, tanto que em outros lugaras eu chamo a *URL* '/' e ele funciona, só no `form` que não. E quando eu passo outra *URL* no `form` ele também funciona:

```
{!! Form::open(['class' => 'form-horizontal search-side-box', 'url' => '/about', 'method' => 'post', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) !!}
```

Comment: O que seu form faz ou deve fazer?

Comment: Nesse caso passa os dados de pesquisa de um item especifico. Se não tiver nenhum campo preenchido ele deve buscar todos os itens, senão busca passando os parametros do form

Comment: @EdinhoRodrigues, vc tem que criar uma rota post: Route::post('/','WebController@index');

Comment: Valeu, resolvi ainda melhor: Route::any('/',  'WebController@index');

Comment: @EdinhoRodrigues, antes de usar a Route::any() verifica a questão de segurança. Tenho que confirmar, mas se não engano favorece vulnerabilidades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom primeiro seu método no Form e nas rotas está errado, em um é definido um post e no outro o get.
Normalmente get é usado para paginas simples, e o post em submissão de formularios e afins, nesse teu caso acho que está faltando um pouco de código aí:

**Defina mais uma rota**

```
Route::get('/', 'WebController@index'); // renderiza a pagina com o form
Route::post('/busca_detalhe', ['as'=>'car.busca_detalhe', 'uses'=> 'WebController@busca_detalhe']); // Retornará os resultados submetidos na busca do form
```

**Adicione uma função no WebController**

```
public function busca_detalhe(Request $request)
{
    $dados = $request->except('_token');
    $cars = DB::table('cars')->select('*')->where('parametro', '=', $dado['parametro'])->->get();
    return view('car.detalhes', compact('cars')); //Crie a view para mostrar os resultados
}
```

Pode também definir a abertura do Form com a route ao invés da url:

```
{!!  Form::open(['route' => 'car.busca_detalhe', 'method' => 'POST', 'class'=>'form-horizontal bordered-row']) !!}
```

Não tente fazer tudo na mesma função/Controller usando as mesmas rotas, isso vai te confundir na hora da manutenção, e nem preciso citar se outro desenvolvedor for analisar teu código um dia...

Comment: Obrigado Darlei, eu fiz a rota passa any, assim posso fazer tanto get qt post, q acha, pode ser assim? EX: Route::any('/', 'WebController@index');

Comment: @EdinhoRodrigues, antes de usar a Route::any() verifica a questão de segurança. Tenho que confirmar, mas se não engano favorece vulnerabilidades.

Comment: Laravel é bem consistente em questão de segurança, mas realmente, qualquer brecha que pode ser evitada é melhor evitar...não custa criar uma rota e uma view novas

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer, verdade! O Laravel é muito robusto quanto a segurança! O problema é o uso inadequado da cultura de implementar para funcionar e embutir vulnerabilidade com isso!